# When comes with did or does?

Tags: questions

When did the school start?

When does the school start?

-- Which of the above looks absolutely correct as per the grammar rules.

Comment: Neither is really idiomatic because of the article. If you drop *the*, it will sound a lot better. But even with the article, they are both grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Both are good,

The first (when did) means a question about the past, for example: "Two days ago, when did the school start?"

The second (when does) means a question about the present or future, for example: "Tomorrow, when does the school start?"